# How to call youtube app from WebView to play videos?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, youtube

I have created an application that uses WebView to view my website, the application is running smoothly and without any bugs, I even uploaded it on the Google Play store. The only thing is that I have youtube video links in my website and they don't work on my application. They appear on the screen and the user can easily click on them, but after clicking the video loading sign appear and stays rotating without any benefit. I know that mobile web browser have no flash player plug-in and I have looked at all the similar questions on StakcOverFlow. So what I would like to do is to make my application call the YouTube app from the android system and let it complete the mission by playing my website youtube videos. I read about Intent methode, but couldn't find anything helpful. Any Suggestions guys?

Thank you svenoaks. Now I have a small error in the code:

```
package com.parse;



import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ParserActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @SuppressLint({"setJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parser);
        myWebView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://parse.com/apps/aramco-app1/push_notifications    /new");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    }
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {webview.loadUrl (url);
    return true;
    {
        // YouTube video link
        if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube:"))
        {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                    (String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s",         url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length())))));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    }


   @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String     description,         String failingUrl)
    {
        Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description,             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
public boolean setIsZoomInEnabled;

}
     class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        private void show()
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
    }

}
```

onReceive method has an Error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me pre KitKat, but now I can't even see the videos in the webview to click on, because of no plug-in. Hopefully it will work for you:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            // YouTube video link
            if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube:"))
            {

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        (String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s", url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length())))));

                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well that looks like I'm forcing my app to launch Youtube app instead of doing nothing whenever the ulr that is being clicked starts with vnd. hence Youtube links. Thank you, but now when I added the code to my WebViewClient I had a problem at the end which pretty much looks like the vriables: <CODE STARTS FROM HERE>       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});<ENDS HERE>  WebActivity and the closing ends have errors